# Why do my Bootstrap cards not line up vertically like the examples on their website?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a web based chat application and I have some images stored in an Amazon S3 bucket. I loop through my servers which are stored in a MongoDB database and fetch all the servers which have been created. The servers each have their own unique image that is displayed in a server list, and they are inconsistent in height and width.

When I try to display them using Bootstrap's card-deck class I was under the impression they should all be displayed the same height and width but this isn't the case for me.

Here is the loop I run to fetch and display the servers:

```
<% _.forEach(chunks, function(val){ %>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card-deck">
                            <% _.forEach(val, function(val2) { %>
                            <div class="card h-100">
                                <form action="/home" method="post" id="fav" class="text-center m-0">
                                    <a href="/servers/<%= val2.name.replace(/ /g, "-") %>">
                                        <img src="www.amazondatabase.com/<%= val2.image %>" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><%= val2.name %> (<%= val2.members.length %>)</h5>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="serverId" id="id" value="<%= val2._id %>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="serverName" id="server_name"
                                               value="<%= val2.name %>">
                                        <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block mt-2">Join Server</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <% }) %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% }) %>
```

When I run this code I get this output:

[image: Output]

As you can see the cards aren't the same height and the footer's don't line up. How would I achieve similar results to the example on their website found here?: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/#card-decks

I have already tried using Bootstrap's card-group class, as well as giving the cards a h-100 class to make the height of the cards 100% but I still have variable height cards. I've also tried adding a class to the images to make them responsive but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Your images in the card is making a difference. I could see your image is a hyperlink. So do one thing, assign a class to it, followed by writing a css class that sets height to it.

Comment: @RohanRao this somewhat helped, to fix it I had to mess around with the columns so that they weren't made too small otherwise the sections of the card would come out of alignment again